# Best way to compress text file list in PHP

Tags: php, text, compression

I have a PHP script that works with a large array of files. The array is serialized and stored in text format like:

```
E:\folder1\folder2\file2.txt|E:\folder1\folder2\file3.txt|E:\folder1\folder3\file1.txt|E:\folder1\folder4\file1.txt|E:\folder1\folder2\file5.txt etc...
```

Using the "|" as split character upon reading the array back from file like: `$array = explode("|",$filesText);`

Given that a large number of the files have identical or similar paths, I would like to compress the string to cut down on file size when stored on disk. How can I compress/decompress the string, and what would be the most efficient way to do it? (smallest file size when stored, and fastest compression/decompression time.)

Comment: what's "large"? 50? 500? 50 kajillion? You'd probably find the overhead of decompressing on every request will outweight the extra overhead of having to read in "raw" text.

Comment: "The array is serialized"; no its not, its a pipe delimited string, you could actully `serialize()` an array if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

[gzcompress](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) and [gzuncompress](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) are what you'll want to use.

Use gzcompress on the string when saving it, use gzuncompress when loading it.  The gzcompress function even includes a compression level option so you can choose a good speed/size tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the class ZipArchive() to compress the string. This should be quite efficient as one step in the compressing algorithm used for ZIP files is to eliminate duplicated parts of the uncompressed data.

If you have got some time, you could also try to use a tree data structure and sort the files by their folder (this should give you the idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29). The serialized tree will in most cases be way smaller than your list.